# Loading image from another domain in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, cross-domain, loader

I have a flash application which is emded into an iframe, that is hosted on my domain (`hc.ru`). However, the **swf** file is situated at `cs1234.vk.me` and loads from there. The iframe is emded in the page which has the `vk.com` domain. In my flash application I want to load an image from domain `cs4321.vk.me`. When I test my flash app locally with local file it works just fine. Here is the code which loads the image:

```
_imgContainer = new Sprite();
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
_imgContainer.addChild(loader);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onError);
loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
loader.mask = mc_holder;
    private function onError(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void 
{
    trace("security error");
    trace(event.text);
}   
private function onLoaderComplete(event:Event):void
{
    trace("the image was loaded");
    this.addChild(_imgContainer);
}
```

When I upload the swf file to server and open it in browser it doesn't show me the image at all. However, there is no any kind of error thrown and trace output says "the image was loaded". All the `cs****.vk.me` servers, which contain both the swf file and the images, have the following `crossdomain.xml` file:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="vk.com" headers="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*.vk.com" headers="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="userapi.com" headers="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*.userapi.com" headers="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="vk.me" headers="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*.vk.me" headers="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="vkontakte.ru" headers="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*.vkontakte.ru" headers="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="mvkontakte.com" headers="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*.mvkontakte.com" headers="*"/>    
<allow-access-from domain="vk.com" to-ports="80"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*.vk.com" to-ports="80"/>
<allow-access-from domain="vk.me" to-ports="80"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*.vk.me" to-ports="80"/>
<allow-access-from domain="userapi.com" to-ports="80"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*.userapi.com" to-ports="80"/>
<allow-access-from domain="vkontakte.ru" to-ports="80"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*.vkontakte.ru" to-ports="80"/>
<allow-access-from domain="mvkontakte.com" to-ports="80"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*.mvkontakte.com" to-ports="80"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I do not really get the problem, since there is no any error of some kind.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try set loader width and height after load

Comment: @IlyaZ It works fine when I test it locally, so it appears to me that cross-domain problem takes place here.

Comment: try add Security.allowDomain("*.vk.me"); Security.loadPolicyFile("http://cs4321.vk.me");